# URI Limit being reached in ADFS SSO login loop

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I am currently implementing a SSO application for a client using Zend and SimpleSamlPHP, and ADFS. They currently have multiple SSO applications set up from their end, and all their users have one of these SSO ADFS set as their default homepage (Intranet site)

We are getting reports that Internet Explorer 8 is throwing a 400 error when a user gets automatically signed in to the Intranet, and then they try to access our application (listed below as SE) in the same tab. This issue is not present in any other browser, or even in different IE tabs or windows. Below are the steps used to recreate the issue.

- My home page in IE is the intranet (MyNet) which also uses SSO:
- Opening IE and once in MyNet, if in the same tab as I try to go to SE, I get HTTP 400 Bad Request
- If I sign out from the intranet and after that go to SE in the same tab, I get HTTP 400 Bad Request
- Opening IE and once in MyNet, I open a second, blank tab (leaving MyNet in the first tab as is) and try to go to SE, SSO works fine and I get to the landing page

This to me seems to have something to do with how IE manages sessions in tabs.

I am awaiting logs from their IT team as this error appears to be coming from ADFS rather than from our end, and no errors are showing in our logs.

I'm wondering if there is anything we can do from our end in terms of manipulating anything to do with the session to get around this error. Below are a few snippets from Zend in terms of setting up sessions:

***Bootstrap.php***

*This is the session init method, the save path has been commented out, as it interfered with the ADFS SSO*

```
    protected function _initSession()
{
    Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
        //'save_path'           => $this->options['resources']['session']['save_path'],
        'use_only_cookies'    => 'on',
        'remember_me_seconds' => 86400,
    ));
    Zend_Session::start();
}
```

---

*UPDATE - 2/4/14 21:47*

Looks like this issue is also happening, but the other way around. If I have a valid SSO login for SE, and then I attempt to view the Intranet I also get the 400 error, but not before the SSO gets stuck in a loop. It appears as if the error is being caused because the Request-URI is too large and hitting the server limit. The return URL is being appended to the end of the request and during the loop the URI gets longer and longer. Are there any ADFS settings that can be changed to avoid this?

---

*UPDATE - 3/4/14 22:35*

The client is using Windows Authentication to automatically log users in that are connected to the corporate network. It looks like we're not getting a valid token back, hence the login loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar because of the token size - in particular when a user has a large number of roles.

Refer : [Office 365 – AD FS Authentication Fails Due To Token Size](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/03/office-365-ad-fs-authentication-fails-due-to-token-size/).

Key point: "The keys “MaxFieldLength” and “MaxRequestBytes” can be added to the registry on the AD FS server and this will allow for a larger HTTP header to accommodate the large Kerberos token. Additional information on these values and their recommended maximums is available in Microsoft KB2020943. A reboot of the AD FS server after applying this change and the users with large Kerberos tokens should be able to authenticate successfully."

Comment: Thanks, will pass this on to their IT guys. Seems bizarre that it is looping though. Seems like we're not getting the token back in the first place, but getting caught in an authentication loop. They are using Windows Authentication for users that are connected to the corporate network.